# Read message with php implementation of google protocol buffers

Tags: php, protocol-buffers

I have an encoded message with Google Procobuf (in C), and I need to decode it in php.

I would like to use [Google Protobuf Php](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/php), but I don't understant how its works, and especially how to decode the message.

Note that I didn't encode the message, I just need to decode it.

Can someone explain to me in detail how it works?

I'm a beginner in php.

Thank you for helpinp me.